# performing operations on a set to obtain desired sequence of sets

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Given $S \subseteq \{1,\ 2,\ \dots \ ,\ n\} $ and the following operations:

1. if $1 \notin S, $ add the element $1$;
2. if $n \in S, $ delete the element $n$;
3. for $1 \leq r \leq n-1,\ $ if $r \in S\ $ and $r+1 \notin S, $ delete the element $r$ and add the element $r+1$;

I'm wondering whether it's possible by these operations for some $n$ to obtain a sequence
$$\emptyset \longrightarrow \{1\} \longrightarrow \{2\} \longrightarrow \dotsm \longrightarrow \{n\}, $$
starting with $\emptyset$ and ending with $\{n\},$ in which each of the $2^n$ subsets of $\{1,\ 2,\ \dots \ ,\ n\}$ appears exactly once. For which n is it possible? In what succession can we use the operations to obtain the desired sequence? Can we prove that it's not possible for any $n$?

Note:
I was working on a simpler problem and proved that $n$ being a number of the form $2^m-1$ is a necessary condition for it and now I'm trying to see if there actually exists such a number $n$ (or potentially a sufficient condition). So far my intuition and trial-and-error suggest that it's not possible.

Comment: +1: Interesting problem.

Comment: is the question well defined? in whar order do you apply operation 3 to a set, do you apply it to r=2,3,..n-1 sequentially?

Comment: @kodlu order of operations is not important as long as we get the desired sequence. Think of operation 3 as just removing an element and adding its successor, it can be performed just once - to an arbitrary element less than _**n**_, there's no restriction on it, whereas, note that operation 2 can only be applied to _**n**_.